# Filtering data with Expression Func - C# - How to apply filter on referent table?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, expression, func

I'm filtering my data with Expressions in c#.

In this particular case I used this piece of code to filter articles / products from my database.

```
private Expression<Func<Article, bool>> GetFilter(ProductsSearchDto productSearchDto)
{
    string stringSearch = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(productSearchDto.stringSearch)
           ? productSearchDto.stringSearch.ToLower()
           : string.Empty;


    return f => (!productSearchDto.BrandId.HasValue || f.BrandId == productSearchDto.BrandId) &&
                ((f.Title.ToLower().Contains(stringSearch)) ||
                (f.ShortDescription.ToLower().Contains(stringSearch)));
}
```

But now I ***would like to filter products by category*** also.
Categories related to products are part of another table since one product might be part of different categories.

```
namespace Entities
{
    public class ArticleCategory
    {
        public long ArticleId { get; set; }
        public Article Article { get; set; }
        public long CategoryId { get; set; }
        public Category Category { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`Article.cs` class has collection of categories:

```
namespace Entities
{
    public class Article
    {
        public long? BrandId { get; set; }
        public Brand Brand { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string ShortDescription { get; set; }
        public ICollection<ArticleCategory> Categories { get; set; }

    }
}
```

`ProductsSearchDto productSearchDto` contains `categoryId` which is used to fetch all products that are part of this specified category.

So I've tried something like this:

```
private Expression<Func<Article, bool>> GetFilter(ProductsSearchDto productSearchDto)
{
    string stringSearch = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(productSearchDto.stringSearch)
           ? productSearchDto.stringSearch.ToLower()
           : string.Empty;


    return f => (!searchQuery.CategoryId.HasValue || f.Categories.Select((x => x.CategoryId).ToList()).Contains((long)searchQuery.CategoryId) &&
                (!productSearchDto.BrandId.HasValue || f.BrandId == productSearchDto.BrandId) &&
                ((f.Title.ToLower().Contains(stringSearch)) ||
                (f.ShortDescription.ToLower().Contains(stringSearch)));
}
```

And this is how it's used in the application:

```
var articles = await _dbContext.Articles
                  .Where(GetFilter(searchObject))
                  .Select(x => new ArticleSimpleGetByCategoryDto
                  {
                      Id = x.Id,
                      Title = x.Title,
                      ShortDescription = x.ShortDescription,
                      Price = x.MPC,
                      Brand = x.Brand != null ? x.Brand.Title : "N/A",
                  })
                  .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

P.S Error image:

[image]
Any kind of help would be awesome!!
Thanks everyone,

Have a nice day/week/month/year :)

Comment: Show how do you use such filter. And which error or bad result do you have.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv it compiles successfully but when I invoke this method I got error that query can't be translated. I will post it in post above.

Comment: Show me that query. And please do not post exception images.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following expression. `ToList()` is bad idea for search query.

```cs
return f => (!searchQuery.CategoryId.HasValue || f.Categories.Any(x => x.CategoryId == searchQuery.CategoryId)
    (!productSearchDto.BrandId.HasValue || f.BrandId == productSearchDto.BrandId) &&
    ((f.Title.ToLower().Contains(stringSearch)) ||
    (f.ShortDescription.ToLower().Contains(stringSearch)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of generating an `Expression<Func<Article,Bool>>`, just pass your `IQueryable<Article>` into the method and compose the expressions there.  eg

```
    private IQueryable<Article> AddFilters(IQueryable<Article> query, ProductsSearchDto productSearchDto)
    {
        if (ProductsSearchDto.BrandId.HasValue)
            query = query.Where(f => f.BrandId == productSearchDto.BrandId;

        //...

        return query;
     }
```